# How to flow a working clock into text?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to place a live clock into a body of text. I need it to flow as if it were just part of the text, but still be live to the local device. Playing around in Adobe Muse I have been able to get a clock into the text, but it segregates itself to its own line rather than flowing like part of the paragraph.

Following is the code Muse produced. I assume I need to make a change to either `actAsInlineDiv normal_text`, or `actAsDiv excludeFromNormalFlow`, or both, but how?

```
 <p id="u3202-10"><span class="Character-Style">You look at the clock on this device and it reads </span><span class="Character-Style"><span class="actAsInlineDiv normal_text" id="u13390"><!-- content --><span class="actAsDiv excludeFromNormalFlow" id="u13388"><!-- custom html --><html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function startTime()
    {
        var today=new Date();
        var h=today.getHours();
        var m=today.getMinutes();
    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    m=checkTime(m);

    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m;
    t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}
function checkTime(i)
{
    if (i<10)
    {
        i="0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">
    <div id="txt"></div>
</body>
</html>
    </span></span></span><span class="Character-Style">As a result you believe that this is the time. As it happens this is the time but unknown to you your device's clock has stopped functioning and is stuck. Does your true belief that this is the time count as knowledge?</span></p>
```

Comment: Is really `setTimeout('startTime()',500);` produced by MUSE? Someone should get fired :)

Comment: Replace <div id="txt"></div> with <span id="txt"></span>.

Comment: The clock was not part of Muse, no. I nabbed it off the net and plugged it in as an HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Muse, but if all you want is a clock of the current time running inline with some text you could do this:

```js
window.onload = displayTime;
function displayTime() {
    var element = document.getElementById("clock");
    var now = new Date();
    var options = {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'};
    element.innerHTML = now.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, options);
    setTimeout(displayTime, 1000);
}
```

```html
The current time is <span id="clock"></span> and it's inline with text.
```

### EDIT

I added these two lines to remove the seconds from display as you requested in your comment.

```
var options = {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'};
element.innerHTML = now.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, options);
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but was hard for me to apply in Muse. Much prettier than what I am doing. Will try to use it in later iterations. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the seconds?

Comment: @grubbug I edited to remove seconds from clock display.